# Downsizing EBS drive on AWS Ubuntu 18 not booting

Tags: 18.04, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to downsize an EBS volume size on AWS on a Ubuntu 18 instance but it's not booting.

Here are the steps I took:

1. Stop the instance
2. Create a snapshot of the boot drive
3. Create a volume from this snapshot (VS)
4. Create a new empty volume with smaller size (VN)
5. Attach VS to /dev/sda1 (2TB)
6. Attach VN to /dev/sdf (200GB)
7. Start the instance
8. Create a partition on VN
9. sudo fdisk /dev/nvme0n1
10. wipefs
11. sudo fdisk /dev/nvme0n1
12. Type 'n', 'p', press enter till it prompts for a new command, then
    press 'w'
13. Format VN’s main partition with an ext4 filesystem
14. mkfs.ext4 /dev/nvme0n1p1
15. Create a mounting directory
16. mkdir /mnt/new-volume
17. Mount VN
18. sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/new-volume
19. Change VN’s e2label to match the one from VS
20. Check it with blkid command
21. sudo e2label /dev/nvme0n1p1 cloudimg-rootfs
22. Copy the content:
23. rsync -vaxSHAX / /mnt/new-volume
24. Unmount VN
25. sudo umount /mnt/new-volume
26. Change the UUID of VN to match VS
27. Check it with blkid command
28. sudo e2fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p1
29. sudo tune2fs -U VS_UUID /dev/nvme0n1p1

Then when I stop the instance, detach all volumes, attach VN to /dev/sda1 and start the instance it does not boot.

The screenshot from the instance shows three lines

SeaBIOS (version 1.6702.14-g...) Machine UUID ec2f1... Booting from Hard Disk 0...

Note that the UUID in the screenshot is different from VS's and VN's original one.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Isn't that a *machine* UUID? It even starts with the telltale hex digits `ec2`, so is probably nothing to do with your disk.

Comment: It does say "Machine UUID" so it may not be related at all

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

Step 4 is causing the issue. Instead I did

Create and start a new instance with same OS and desired lower volume size (VN). Stop instance and detach the volume VN.

Then steps 8-12 are not needed.

Answer (score -1):

Did you create this new instance with the new volume size in the same availability zone as the one you wanted to shrink? I am asking because I am having the same issues, but these are the steps I took.

1. Create a snapshot of the volume in the same availability zone as the instance by stopping the instance.
2. Use the snapshot to create a new volume of the same size in the same availability zone as the volume you want to reduce.
3. Create a blank new volume with the size that you want to resize the old one to.
4. Attach the two volumes to the instance and then restart the instance.
5. Note the new volume labels by entering `sudo lsblk -e7`
6. Check the volume information by using `sudo hwinfo --disk --short` after installing hwinfo.
7. Create a filesystem for the two new volumes by entering `sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xvdf` and `sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xvdg` Replace xvdf and xvdg with the name of the volumes and note the new names if on newer distros like nitro systems.
8. Create two mount directories and mount the two volumes:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /mnt/small 
   sudo mount /dev/xvdf /mnt/small 
   sudo mkdir /mnt/snap 
   sudo mount /dev/xvdg1 /mnt/snap
   ```

   Replace xvdf and xvdg with the name of the volumes and note the new names if on newer distros like nitro systems.
9. Sync the files with `sudo rsync -ahaxxsp /mnt/snap/ /mnt/small`
10. Unmount the smaller volume `sudo umount /dev/xvdf`
11. Stop the instance and detach all the volumes.
12. Attach the small volume (small volume size you want) and attach to the block device name from the original block device name which is usually `/dev/sda1` .
13. Restart the instance and verify that everything works correctly.

After doing this, the instance remained in a loop and was stuck at initializing.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1230951)